# Runtime error in a C program to find an index of an element

Tags: c

This program prints the index of element after sorted. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

int n;
int value[10000];
int index[10000];
int enable[10000];

//return the element which is smallest and never selected
int min() {
    int i, tmp=INT_MAX;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (enable[i] == 0 && tmp > value[i] )
            tmp = value[i];
    }
    return tmp;
}

void solve() {
    int i,j;
    int tmp;
    for (i= 0; i < n; i++) {
        tmp = min();
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (enable[j] == 0 && tmp == value[j] ) {
                index[j] = i + 1;
                enable[j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void print() {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < n-1; i++) 
        printf("%d ", index[i]);
    printf("%d\n", index[i]);
}

int main() {
    int i;
    while (scanf("%d", &n) != EOF) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &value[i]);
        }
        solve();
        print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It worked well on my computer, but the online judge shows runtime error. I could not figure it out where it went wrong, maybe my test is not enough.

Comment: You should compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use a debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: What are constrains for n?

Comment: What happens if `n` is 23456 ?

Comment: the value range for n is 1<=n<=10000

Comment: I fill its related to the `EOF` `while (scanf("%d", &n) != EOF) {` try maybe another condition.